# Find files with extensions given in arguments using regex

Tags: bash, files, find, regular-expression, arguments

Let's say a have a following command

```
search /home/user proc .h .c .txt ...
```

I am building a script with `find` command to get all files that start with given name and end with one of given extensions.

I've managed to build this using a loop:

```
directory=$1
fileName=$2
fileExtensions=""

for arg in "$@"
do
    #skipping first and second argument
     if [ $arg = $1 -o $arg = $2 ]; then 
        continue;
    fi
    fileExtensions+="${arg//.}\|"
done
#removing the last '|', otherwise regex parser error occurs
fileExtensions=${fileExtensions::-1}

find $directory -name "$fileName*" -regex ".*\.\($fileExtensions)"
```

Is there more elegant way of achieving this using regex?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script could be reduced to:

```
directory=$1
fileName=$2
shift 2

a="$*"    b="${*#.}"
(( ${#a} - ${#b} - $# )) && echo "some extension(s) is(are) missing a leading dot." >&2

fileExtensions="$(IFS=\|; echo "${*#.}")"

find "$directory" -name "$fileName*" -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*\.($fileExtensions)$"
```

By default, find accepts regex of type emacs, to use that type several backslashes are necessary, like `\|`. That could be avoided by using a different type of regex (as above).

Where `${*#.}` removes the leading dot (if it exists) and join all the remaining "Positional Parameters" with the value of the first character of IFS, which was set to be `|` for the execution of the subshell.

Just one variable assignment with one "Parameter Expansion", that's all that's needed.

---

**EDIT**
The `(( ${#a} - ${#b} - $# ))` is used to check whether all the extensions provided in the argument list start with a dot.

The character count (`${#a}`) of all arguments concatenated (`a=$*`)
should be equal to
the character count (`${#b}`) of all arguments concatenated (one leading dot removed) (`b=${*#.}`)
plus
the number of arguments (`$#`).

```
${#a} == ${#b} + $#
```

If and only if all arguments have one leading dot.

As an arithmetic test:

```
((  ${#a} - (${#b} + $#)  ))
```

Or also:

```
((  ${#a} - ${#b} - $#  )) && echo "missing leading dot(s)."
```

---

## Edit II

The list of extensions given in the command line arguments is processed here:

```
fileExtensions="$(IFS=\|; echo "${*#.}")"
```

Here is how it works, inside out:

```
$*   # This generates a string of all positional arguments using IFS.
```

From `LESS=+'/Special Parameters' man bash`:

> That is, "$*" is equivalent to "$1c$2c...", where c is the first character of the value of the IFS variable.

Then we use "parameter expansion" to cut the front of each positional argument:

```
${parameter#word}     # used as ${*# } above.
```

From `LESS=+/'parameter#word' man bash`:

> If parameter is @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

The `word` in the previous expansion is set to a dot `.`, thus removing the dots in the front of all positional parameters.

As the IFS at that point starts with an `|` character, that is used to build a string with `|` as the separator for the parameter list that has been striped of a dot in the front.

That string is provided to the command echo to make it printed.
But before the echo command is executed, the variable `$IFS` is set to a `|`.

That is wrapped inside a command execution `$(…)` (to create a sub shell that will forget the change to IFS when it ends).

Then we assign the string to a variable:

```
fileExtensions="$(IFS=\|; echo "${*#.}")"
```

In short: that transforms `.c .h .txt` into `c|h|txt`.

Comment: Sorry for bringing this back, but I try to understand how `"$(IFS=\|; echo "${*#.}")"` works. I know what it does, but how does it do it? I know we launch this in a subshell and we replace the dafault internal field separator with |, but why then we call `echo "${*#.}")"` and what each character in `${*#.}` mean/do?

Comment: @Dandry Read my `Edit II`. Does it clear your questions?

Comment: I wish I could've upvoted you more. Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 2):

That seems the regex should work, and the only other option I can come up with is something like `-name "proc*" \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" ... \)`
which probably isn't that much simpler.

Some small things that could be done:

1) You can use `shift` to get rid of `$1` and `$2`, instead of the conditional inside the loop.

2) You could combine the `-name` and `-regex`, so that in the end, you'd have `-regex ".*/proc.*\.(c|h|txt)"`

3) If you want to make the code shorter, you can join the positional parameters with `IFS` and `$*`:

```
$ set .c .h
$ IFS='|'
$ echo "(${*/./})"
(c|h)
```

<sub>(I'm not saying anything about readability or elegance.)</sub>